# Newtons law of cooling.

Tags: physics, problem-solving

A body originally at $80$ degree Celsius cools down to $60$ degree Celsius in $20$ minutes.The temperature of air being $40$ degree Celsius. What will be the temperature of the body after $40$ minutes from the original ?

Comment: Best suited for physics SE, thought there is some math regarding the differential equation part. What have you done?

Comment: This question would be closed on PSE without hesitation; I don't recommend the OP to post there.

Comment: I also recommend you see here: http://www.meritnation.com/ask-answer/question/a-body-cools-from-80-c-to-50-c-in-5-minutes-cal/thermal-properties-of-matter/6306186

Comment: This question will be also put on hold in physics SE, because it violate the homework policy...

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Newton's law of cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_law_of_cooling#Temperature_function-of-time_solution_in_terms_of_object_heat_capacity), you have to solve the differential equation
$$T'(t)=-r(T(t)-T_{\text{air}})$$
where $T(t)$ is the temperature of the body at at time $t$ and $r$ is some positive constant. The solution is
$$T(t)=T_{\text{air}}+(T(0)-T_{\text{air}}))e^{-rt}.$$
Since $T_{\text{air}}=40^{\circ}$ and $T(0)=80^{\circ}$, it follows that
$$T(t)=40+40e^{-rt}.$$
If $T(20)=60^{\circ}$, what is $T(40)$?